# Unescaping backslash in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I wanna unescape backslashes in user input strings to use them for regex replacement.

Escaping backslashes is easily done with  `NSRegularExpression.escapedTemplate(for: "\\n")`. This returns `"\\\\n"` as expected. However how can I backward transform them, for example, like `\\n` (backslash + n) to `\n` (return)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've improved @kabiroberai's code to be more functional and to remove remaining single backslashes.

```swift
    extension String {
        var unescaped: String {
            let entities = ["\0": "\\0",
                            "\t": "\\t",
                            "\n": "\\n",
                            "\r": "\\r",
                            "\"": "\\\"",
                            "\'": "\\'",
                            ]
            
            return entities
                .reduce(self) { (string, entity) in
                    string.replacingOccurrences(of: entity.value, with: entity.key)
                }
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\(?!\\\\)", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\", with: "\\")
        }
    }
```

---

### Update (2018)

I found my previous code doesn't unescape correctly in some cases.

So, I updated my production code. The following is the latest one I use.
I'm not sure I really need to do this complex process, but it seems working better now.

```
var unescaped: String {
    let entities = ["\0": "0",
                    "\t": "t",
                    "\n": "n",
                    "\r": "r",
                    "\"": "\"",
                    "\'": "'",
                    ]
    
    return entities
        .mapValues { try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*(\\\\" + $0 + ")") }
        .reduce(self) { (string, entity) in
            entity.value.matches(in: string, range: string.nsRange)
                .map { $0.range(at: 1) }
                .reversed()
                .reduce(string) { ($0 as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: $1, with: entity.key) }
        }
}
```

### Update 2 (2023-12-02, Swift 5.9)

The issue of all previous versions is they could not unescape continuous backslashes properly. I believe the version below resolves the issue and enough simple to adopt.

```swift
extension String {

    /// Unescaped version of the string by unescaping the characters with backslashes.
    var unescaped: String {
       let entities = [
            #"0"#: "\0",  // null character
            #"t"#: "\t",  // horizontal tab
            #"n"#: "\n",  // line feed
            #"r"#: "\r",  // carriage return
            #"""#: "\"",  // double quotation mark
            #"'"#: "\'",  // single quotation mark
            #"\"#: "\\",  // backslash
        ]
        return self.replacing(/\\([0tnr"'\\])/) { entities[String($0.1)]! }
    }
}

final class StringExtensionsTests: XCTestCase {

    func testUnescaping() {
        XCTAssertEqual(#"\\"#.unescaped, "\\")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"\'"#.unescaped, "\'")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"\""#.unescaped, "\"")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"a\n   "#.unescaped, "a\n   ")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"a\\n  "#.unescaped, "a\\n  ")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"a\\\n "#.unescaped, "a\\\n ")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"a\\\\n"#.unescaped, "a\\\\n")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"\\\\\t"#.unescaped, "\\\\\t")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"\\foo\\\\\0bar\\"#.unescaped, "\\foo\\\\\u{0}bar\\")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"\\\\\\\\foo"#.unescaped, "\\\\\\\\foo")
        XCTAssertEqual(#"foo: \r\n1"#.unescaped, "foo: \r\n1")
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the last to lines with `.replacingOccurrences(...)`? Your solution seems to work fine without them.

Comment: ```Type of expression is ambiguous without more context```

Comment: This is so unnecessarily complex and doesn't make any sense. Look at Popmedic's solution below.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think it is possible to do this automatically, however, as there are only a few escaped characters in Swift, you can put them into an array, loop through them, and then replace all instances with the unescaped version. Here's a String extension I made that does this:

```
extension String {
    var unescaped: String {
        let entities = ["\0", "\t", "\n", "\r", "\"", "\'", "\\"]
        var current = self
        for entity in entities {
            let descriptionCharacters = entity.debugDescription.characters.dropFirst().dropLast()
            let description = String(descriptionCharacters)
            current = current.replacingOccurrences(of: description, with: entity)
        }
        return current
    }
}
```

To use it, simply access the property. For example,

```
print("Hello,\\nWorld!".unescaped)
```

will print

```
Hello,
World!
```

Comment: I've also just found such escaped characters are limited in Swift. If there is no magical, easy way, it's better to extend String and create original property. Thanks.

Comment: characters.dropFirst().dropLast()
'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly
not working @kabiroberai

Answer (score 5):

Here are my escape and unescaped for a string

```swift
let given =     "{\n\t\"test\": \"this  \\ \",\n\r\t\"\'testing\': 1\r\n}\\ \0 \\"
let expected = #"{\n\t\"test\": \"this  \\ \",\n\r\t\"\'testing\': 1\r\n}\\ \0 \\"#
let expectedAscii = #"{\n\t\"test\": \"this \u{0001F603} \\ \",\n\r\t\"\'testing\': 1\r\n}\\ \0 \\"#

extension String {
    private static let escapedChars = [
        (#"\0"#, "\0"),
        (#"\t"#, "\t"),
        (#"\n"#, "\n"),
        (#"\r"#, "\r"),
        (#"\""#, "\""),
        (#"\'"#, "\'"),
        (#"\\"#, "\\")
    ]
    var escaped: String {
        self.unicodeScalars.map { $0.escaped(asASCII: false) }.joined()
    }
    var asciiEscaped: String {
        self.unicodeScalars.map { $0.escaped(asASCII: true) }.joined()
    }
    var unescaped: String {
        var result: String = self
        String.escapedChars.forEach {
            result = result.replacingOccurrences(of: $0.0, with: $0.1)
        }
        return result
    }
}

print(expected == given.escaped)
print(expectedAscii == given.asciiEscaped)
print(given.escaped.unescaped == given)
print(expected.unescaped == given)
print(expected.unescaped.escaped == expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way is to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

```
let input = "My name is \\n and \\n"
let firstmod = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\n", withString: "\n", options: [], range: nil)

Input : "My name is \\n and \\n"
Output: "My name is \n and \n"
```

Comment: I wanted do it in general, and not \\\\ to \\ but \\ to \. So like `\\n` to `\n` and `\\t` to `\t`.

Comment: But how about `\r` and `\"` and `\\`... Ok, well, it is a way to replace all those combinations...

Comment: Use loop to iterate and changes elements

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the only way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me, here is what worked for me:

```swift
extension String {

    var unescaped: String {
        guard let convertedString = (self as NSString).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableString else {
            return self
        }
        CFStringTransform(convertedString, nil, NSString(string: "Any-Hex/Java"), true)
        return String(convertedString)
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this, it only un-escaped \u- (unicode hex code point) escapes.  For example, `print("X\\u000AY\\nZ".unescaped)` only turns the first escape into a newline, but not the second.  (X, Y, and Z would all output as separate lines if it worked.  But Y and Z are on one line separated by the literal pair of characters `\n`.)  That's actually consistent with the [docs](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/general/#general) for the "Any-Hex" transforms.  It only indicates Unicode code point escapes, not other types.  Interesting function though.  Never heard of it before.